# SQL Server Browser showing only hostname, not instance name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express, sqlbrowser

I just setup a new Windows Server 2008 machine with an instance of SQL Server 2008 Express.  The SQL Browser service does not appear to be working correctly.  In Management Studio, browsing for servers shows the hostname of the new server, but not the instance name.  When you choose the hostname form the list it doesn't connect.  But I can connect manually by typing the hostname\instancename combination.

update 1:

1. The browser service is running, and I have tried it with several different accounts, including domain administrator which is a bad practice, but I tried anyway for troubleshooting purposes.
2. I have tried punching the appropriate holes in the firewall, and also completely turning the firewall off.
3. This is running on a Hyper-V, Windows Server 2008 32 bit guest, which is on a Windows Server 2008 64-bit host.  I have done this before (without issues) on this same host, but with SQL 2008 Standard instead of Express.
4. When I browse for the server in SSMS(Express) on the SQL Server machine, it works fine and shows the whole instance name.  When I browse for it on a remote machine (on the same intranet) with SSMS (standard) it just shows the host name.

update 2:

Followed the packets as suggested and found the following

1. The client sent the broadcast as expected and received correct responses from other SQL Servers on the same network.
2. The server received the broadcast but did not send a response.

Considering these results, I wonder why the host name ever appears in the client list in the first place.  It shouldn't show up at all, right?

update 3:

Spent an hour and a half on the phone with Microsoft support.  I learned a few things, but the problem is not yet solved.  It was suggested that I try installing an instance of SQL Standard on the same machine.  I did that and the new instance exhibits all the same symptoms.  The hostname shows up in the browse list only once, not once for each instance.

update 4:

Stackoverflow chose an answer for me thanks to the bounty system, but this question is not answered.  Today I tried moving the whole VM to a different host server - everything is exactly the same.  The hostname still appears in the browse list, without the instance name.

update 5:

Confirmed that Hyper-V Integration Services are installed on the guest (SQL) server.

Comment: :( is it possibly something to do with hyper-v and the NIC driver or something else low-level like that? is it between two VM's guests on the same host?

Comment: It is possible.  But both of these hyper-v hosts have had other guests with sql server which have not shown these symptoms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check that the browser service is running, it's not turned on by default.

**UPDATE1:**  See if you can install [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=f4db40af-1e08-4a21-a26b-ec2f4dc4190d&displaylang=en)/[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to do a network trace on the SQL Server to see if it's receiving the broadcasts and sending responses.  I think this is your best option in troubleshooting this issue. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx) the service uses UDP port 1434, so this is the traffic to watch.

**UPDATE2:** Does the server have multiple IP's?  according to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181.aspx) the Windows Server 2008 firewall has issues responding to SQL Browser service broadcasts, even with rules allowing packets through.

Comment: is the client & server in the same broadcast domain? i.e subnet?

Comment: Yes, we are on the same subnet.

Comment: Only one IPv4 address - but that's an interesting link.  I have tried shutting the firewall off completely.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear.  I tried shutting the firewall off, and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I tend not to rely on browsing. You'll get inconsistent results because browsing sends out a broadcast udp/1434 packet and waits for responses back. However, since you are able to connect remotely via SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME, that aspect of the SQL Browser service is working. If it wasn't, you wouldn't have been able to connect. With that said, to troubleshoot the browsing portion:

- Have you tried stopping and restarting the SQL Browser Service?
- Have you tried stopping and restarting the instance if that didn't work?

To completely troubleshoot this, unfortunately, you'd have to do packet traces.

Comment: Yes, I've done both of these.  Also rebooted both client and server dozens of times - after practically every change I've tried.  There is nothing critical on the new machine yet, so rebooting is not an issue.

Comment: It's a good point, the browser service is actually working to some extent, or I wouldn't be able to connect - it is setup for dynamic ports.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the browsing service is messed up somehow...

I don't know if you can temporarily take this SQL Server down temporarily.  But if so, you may want to try this:

1. Uninstall all SQL\instances completely.
2. Run the install of SQL Express 2008
3. Create a default instance during install (Not a named instance)
4. Run the installer again and create the default named instance (SQLExpress)
5. Try connecting to the named instance again.  If it works, you can remove the default instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a VM. After shutting down the Firewall it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue.  I was not able to see Instance Names in the SSMS Network Servers tab.  It turned out that I had set up Hyper-V and created an Internal Network on my local machine.  That network was identified as a Public/Guest Network and the Windows Firewall was ENABLED for it, even though my Domain setting has the Firewall DISABLED.  Once I disabled that guest network on my computer I could see all the instances.

Machines:
Physical SQL Server 2014 Ent
Windows 8.1 laptop running Hyper-V